# Listing objects from each and every bucket present in my s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have 5 buckets in my S3. I have to list objects for every bucket present in my s3 by python script. I am writing script something like this :

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()

print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    for obj in bucket.object.all(['bucket']):
        response = obj.get(
            Key, StorageClass, Size)
        print(response)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: Actually There are so many errors. The second for loop is not written in correct way .

Comment: _WHY_ do you want to list all objects? How often are you doing this? What are you doing with the output? What is your question? Please edit your Question to add more information instead of replying in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = s3.list_buckets()
    
    for bucket_info in response['Buckets']:
        
        bucket = s3r.Bucket(bucket_info['Name'])
        
        print('Existing buckets:',  bucket_info['Name'])
        
        for object in bucket.objects.all():
            print(' - ', object.key)
```